# What is the name of this plumbing U wedge + connection

Tags: plumbing-fixture

The two black pipes pictured below are connected, and a U-shaped wedge is placed between them, apparently to close the connection.

[image: U-shaped wedge connecting two pipes]

What is the name of this connection or this wedge?

I will subsequently google the name you provide to look for how I can open the joint and reseal it.

Comment: I have never seen plastic pipe held together with a single point are you sure that is what it is I would think it is more or a hold down , if it was to seal the pipe there would need to be one for each pipe on the coupling.

Comment: What is that pipe used for? That is special piping with proprietary push-fit connectors that are locked with that u-clip and it is not standard "plumbing" pipe. What is the application (e.g. rain water collection, gray-water system, agriculture/irrigation, recreational vehicle, fish tank, spa, pond...)?

Comment: Where on the planet is this?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Each of the two pipes connects to a simple solar water heater, installed over the roof of a house in Canada. Might this be a very specific type of connector, created for just this application (and making it impossible to fix by off-the-shelf parts)?

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think a seal failure is the issue, that leak seems to be from where that U clamp holds the joint together.

I suggest you need to replace the whole joint so a section of pipe and two joints will be needed.

Comment: What is the name of this joint, so I can search for a replacement?